# How to get an element by it's tag between to div tags in JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inside two div tags a tag named `path` which I want to hide when I click on the div id `toto` but not for `tata`.

Can I do that with JavaScript?

```
<div id="tata">
    <path style="stroke-dasharray: 1009.6, 1009.6; stroke-dashoffset: 0; transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.8s ease-in 0s;" d="M6.987,4.774c15.308,2.213,30.731,1.398,46.101,1.398 c9.74,0,19.484,0.084,29.225,0.001c2.152-0.018,4.358-0.626,6.229,1.201c-5.443,1.284-10.857,2.58-16.398,2.524 c-9.586-0.096-18.983,2.331-28.597,2.326c-7.43-0.003-14.988-0.423-22.364,1.041c-4.099,0.811-7.216,3.958-10.759,6.81 c8.981-0.104,17.952,1.972,26.97,1.94c8.365-0.029,16.557-1.168,24.872-1.847c2.436-0.2,24.209-4.854,24.632,2.223 c-14.265,5.396-29.483,0.959-43.871,0.525c-12.163-0.368-24.866,2.739-36.677,6.863c14.93,4.236,30.265,2.061,45.365,2.425 c7.82,0.187,15.486,1.928,23.337,1.903c2.602-0.008,6.644-0.984,9,0.468c-2.584,1.794-8.164,0.984-10.809,1.165 c-13.329,0.899-26.632,2.315-39.939,3.953c-6.761,0.834-13.413,0.95-20.204,0.938c-1.429-0.001-2.938-0.155-4.142,0.436 c5.065,4.68,15.128,2.853,20.742,2.904c11.342,0.104,22.689-0.081,34.035-0.081c9.067,0,20.104-2.412,29.014,0.643 c-4.061,4.239-12.383,3.389-17.056,4.292c-11.054,2.132-21.575,5.041-32.725,5.289c-5.591,0.124-11.278,1.001-16.824,2.088 c-4.515,0.885-9.461,0.823-13.881,2.301c2.302,3.186,7.315,2.59,10.13,2.694c15.753,0.588,31.413-0.231,47.097-2.172 c7.904-0.979,15.06,1.748,22.549,4.877c-12.278,4.992-25.996,4.737-38.58,5.989c-8.467,0.839-16.773,1.041-25.267,0.984 c-4.727-0.031-10.214-0.851-14.782,1.551c12.157,4.923,26.295,2.283,38.739,2.182c7.176-0.06,14.323,1.151,21.326,3.07 c-2.391,2.98-7.512,3.388-10.368,4.143c-8.208,2.165-16.487,3.686-24.71,5.709c-6.854,1.685-13.604,3.616-20.507,4.714 c-1.707,0.273-3.337,0.483-4.923,1.366c2.023,0.749,3.73,0.558,5.95,0.597c9.749,0.165,19.555,0.31,29.304-0.027 c15.334-0.528,30.422-4.721,45.782-4.653"></path>
</div>

<div id="toto">
    <path style="stroke-dasharray: 1009.6, 1009.6; stroke-dashoffset: 0; transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.8s ease-in 0s;" d="M6.987,4.774c15.308,2.213,30.731,1.398,46.101,1.398 c9.74,0,19.484,0.084,29.225,0.001c2.152-0.018,4.358-0.626,6.229,1.201c-5.443,1.284-10.857,2.58-16.398,2.524 c-9.586-0.096-18.983,2.331-28.597,2.326c-7.43-0.003-14.988-0.423-22.364,1.041c-4.099,0.811-7.216,3.958-10.759,6.81 c8.981-0.104,17.952,1.972,26.97,1.94c8.365-0.029,16.557-1.168,24.872-1.847c2.436-0.2,24.209-4.854,24.632,2.223 c-14.265,5.396-29.483,0.959-43.871,0.525c-12.163-0.368-24.866,2.739-36.677,6.863c14.93,4.236,30.265,2.061,45.365,2.425 c7.82,0.187,15.486,1.928,23.337,1.903c2.602-0.008,6.644-0.984,9,0.468c-2.584,1.794-8.164,0.984-10.809,1.165 c-13.329,0.899-26.632,2.315-39.939,3.953c-6.761,0.834-13.413,0.95-20.204,0.938c-1.429-0.001-2.938-0.155-4.142,0.436 c5.065,4.68,15.128,2.853,20.742,2.904c11.342,0.104,22.689-0.081,34.035-0.081c9.067,0,20.104-2.412,29.014,0.643 c-4.061,4.239-12.383,3.389-17.056,4.292c-11.054,2.132-21.575,5.041-32.725,5.289c-5.591,0.124-11.278,1.001-16.824,2.088 c-4.515,0.885-9.461,0.823-13.881,2.301c2.302,3.186,7.315,2.59,10.13,2.694c15.753,0.588,31.413-0.231,47.097-2.172 c7.904-0.979,15.06,1.748,22.549,4.877c-12.278,4.992-25.996,4.737-38.58,5.989c-8.467,0.839-16.773,1.041-25.267,0.984 c-4.727-0.031-10.214-0.851-14.782,1.551c12.157,4.923,26.295,2.283,38.739,2.182c7.176-0.06,14.323,1.151,21.326,3.07 c-2.391,2.98-7.512,3.388-10.368,4.143c-8.208,2.165-16.487,3.686-24.71,5.709c-6.854,1.685-13.604,3.616-20.507,4.714 c-1.707,0.273-3.337,0.483-4.923,1.366c2.023,0.749,3.73,0.558,5.95,0.597c9.749,0.165,19.555,0.31,29.304-0.027 c15.334-0.528,30.422-4.721,45.782-4.653"></path>
</div>
```

This is the code to add a CSS style to my element:

```
$("path").css("display", "none");
```

But the issue now is that I want to add that style only for the `path` tag which is in div id `toto`.

NB: the tag named `Path` doesn't have an id and I can't add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following expression would target the `path` element during the click handler of the div `toto` and hide it.

```
$('#toto').on('click',function()
{
       $(this).find("path").hide();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6f27kap1/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can select the div that contains the path element that you want and then find the path tag below it.

```
$('#toto').find('path').css('display', 'none');
```

https://api.jquery.com/find/

You can also just directly refer to the element:

```
$('#toto path').css('display', 'none');
```

But iirc using `find()` will result in some optimizations for finding the elements in your code.